# Ember.js How to properly filter a model in a component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following auto complete component:
*Initial idea from EmberCasts: [Building an Autocomplete Widget Part 1](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/building-an-autocomplete-widget-part-1)*

```
App.AutoCompleteComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    searchText: null,

    searchResults: function() {
        var model = this.get('model');
        var searchText = this.get('searchText');

        console.log(this.get('model')); // shows array

        if (searchText){
            console.log('searching for: ' + searchText); // shows up in console with searchText

            var regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
            model = model.filterBy('name', function(name) {
                console.log(name); // never got reached
                return name.match(regex);
            });
        }

        return model;
    }.property('searchText')
});
```

My **template**:

```
{{auto-complete model=controllers.categories}}

<script type="text/x-handlebars"s data-template-name="components/auto-complete">
    {{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Search..."}}
    <ul>
        {{#each searchResults}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

The problem is, that no model item get returned. At the initial state of the program all my categories are shown - I will fix that soon. But it shows me that the auto-complete component does work. The model does get returned at first. 
I think  the `FilterBy` does not what I expect it should do.

I have tried to change the FilterBy part to this and search exactly for the name:

```
model = model.filterBy('name', searchText);
```

But that did also not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're second approach is the correct one with `filterBy`, if you want to pass a function you would use `filter`.

```
model = model.filterBy('name', searchText);
```

I bet name doesn't exist on your models, or something along those lines.  If you need more help show us an example of the categories model.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oTIxAjI/1/edit

You'll want to use filter

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oTIxAjI/4/edit

Comment: Your js bin does indeed work. But only for exact match. I want it to find the red color item with only a "r" for example. I thought that could be accomplished with filterBy. Here you have an edited js bin with my model on the bottom: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oTIxAjI/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: use filter then, see example above

Comment: Many thanks, did not see the use of `filter` before! I have edited the js bin so that it also is case insensitive: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oTIxAjI/8/edit